# Trivial context manager in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement

My resource can by of type `R1` which requires locking or of type `R2`
which does not require it:

```
class MyClass(object):   # broken
    def __init__ (self, ...):
        if ...:
            self.resource = R1(...)
            self.lock = threading.Lock()
        else:
            self.resource = R2(...)
            self.lock = None

    def foo(self):   # there are many locking methods
        with self.lock:
            operate(self.resource)
```

The above obviously fails if `self.lock` is `None`.

## My options are:

1. `if`:

   ```
   def foo(self):
       if self.lock:
           with self.lock:
               operate(self.resource)
       else:
           operate(self.resource)
   ```

   - cons: too verbose
   - pro: does not create an unnecessary `threading.Lock`
2. always set `self.lock` to `threading.Lock`

   - pro: code is simplified
   - cons: `with self.lock` appears to be relatively expensive
     (comparable to disk i/o!)
3. define a trivial lock class:

   ```
   class TrivialLock(object):
       def __enter__(self): pass
       def __exit__(self, _a, _b, _c): pass
       def acquire(self): pass
       def release(self): pass
   ```

   and use it instead of `None` for `R2`.

   - pro: simple code
   - cons: I have to define `TrivialLock`

## Questions

1. What method is preferred by the community?
2. Regardless of (1), does anyone actually define something like
   `TrivialLock`? (I actually expected that something like that would be
   in the standard library...)
3. Is my observation that locking cost is comparable to that of a
   `write` conforms to expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define `TrivialLock`. It can be even more trivial, though, since you just need a context manager, not a lock.

```
class TrivialLock(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(*args):
        pass
```

You can make this even more trivial using `contextlib`:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def TrivialLock():
    yield

self.lock = TrivialLock()
```

And since `yield` can be an expression, you can define `TrivalLock` inline instead:

```
self.lock = contextlib.contextmanager(lambda: (yield))()
```

Note the parentheses; `lambda: yield` is invalid. However, the generator expression `(yield)` makes this a single-use context manager; if you try to use the same value in a second `with` statement, you get a `Runtime` error because the `generator` is exhausted.

Comment: This is a "sunny weather raincoat": `with contextlib.contextmanager(lambda: (yield))(): raise Exception` fails with `RuntimeError: generator didn't yield`.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I just get the raised `Exception` in Python 2.7 and 3.6, as expected.

Comment: Python 2.7.14. Sorry, the shortcut does not work.  `lock = contextlib.contextmanager(lambda: (yield))()` then `with lock: raise Exception` results in `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 19, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield")
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
`

Comment: Strange; I do *not* get that error (Python 2.7.10, but I get the same non-error result in Python 3.6 as well.)

Comment: Ah, the generator makes a single-use context manager, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/library/contextlib.rst under "Single use, reusable and reentrant context managers".